# Service Fabric include additional files

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, azure-service-fabric

I have a Visual Studios solution containing the following:

- Service Fabric project
- Stateless Service Project

The stateless service project uses configuration-based dependency injection, meaning the dependencies are loosly coupled with the project itself and not actual VS "project/compilation dependencies".

I would like to continue to use Visual Studios, but when I deploy this project it doesn't know about the assembly dependencies (as these are only defined in DI configuration) and therefore it doesn't package up the necessary files and throws exceptions trying to perform dependency injection.

Is there any way in the ApplicationManifest.xml file or one of the other many XML files that Visual Studios provides that I can specify additional files (i.e. my dependent assemblies) to be published to Service Fabric as part of the deployment?

Ideally, I'd like to automate this file to be generated as part of my automated build script.

Comment: @leppie - why remove the Visual Studio 2015 tag from this post? The Visual Studio Service Fabric Add-on is the cause of the limitation, not Service Fabric or the Azure API itself?

Comment: You are not coding a VS component or plugin. Dont tag the tool.

Comment: Although this is not the direct answer to my question, I found that deploying my application manually outside of Visual Studios was the best way forward for us. This gave me ultimate control over what goes into the package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to encapsulate this behavior into the Service project itself, you could edit the service's project file to include MSBuild logic which dynamically includes <Content> items to the project that have CopyToOutputDirectory set to Always or PreserveNewest.  These items would be dynamically included at build time based on the configuration of your DI.  Since the service project is "declaring" that it has these content items, they will be copied to the service's package folder.

Another option is to add logic at the Application project during the Package step.  You can implement a target there like this:

```
<Target Name="AfterPackage" AfterTargets="Package">
  <!-- Copy dependency files to service package location -->
</Target>
```

Your logic there would do the same type of reading of your DI configuration but, rather than adding <Content> items, it would simply copy the files to the appropriate location within the application package whose path is defined by $(PackageLocation).

Comment: I'm pretty new to msbuild so this may be a silly question, but are there a list of variables defined somewhere that we can use to make sure we're copying files to right place? I see in the comments here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-manage-application-in-visual-studio/#package-your-service-fabric-application that you've referenced "$(PackageLocation)". Are there others?

Comment: There are plenty of built-in MSBuild properties that exist but PackageLocation is defined by the Service Fabric tooling.  There is not such a published list for those properties by the Service Fabric tooling.  You can see those that are defined by looking at the .targets file that is imported by each Application project at C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Service Fabric Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.ApplicationPackage.targets.  But to do the copying, all that's really needed is PackageLocation and the name of your service folder in the package.

Comment: Is this going to be a "safe" solution going forward? Since it's referencing variables defined in an external targets file, I worry that you guys might change the name of the targets in the future.

Comment: That property is intended to be consumed by users exactly for this purpose.  It won't be changed.

Comment: Where exactly this `Target` tag should go? `ApplicationManifest` file?

Comment: How does this work for .NET Core-based services?  They don't use MSBuild AFAIK.

Answer (score 5):

Using Matt's suggestion above, I got this to work in my sfproj to copy some native dlls required by my application.  Just in case anyone has this same use case:

```
<Target Name="AfterPackage" AfterTargets="Package">
    <Copy SourceFiles="ApplicationPackageRoot\mynative.dll" DestinationFolder="$(PackageLocation)\MyServicePkg\Code"/>
  </Target>
```

Comment: Where exactly this `Target` tag should go? `ApplicationManifest` file?

Comment: It should go in your .sfproj project file.  This is just normal MSBuild stuff.

Comment: Using Adam's answer we were able to add our XMLDOC's to the package (We use this for Swagger UI via a NuGet Package).

It would be great if Service Fabric default was to package everything in the bin from the service project into the code package.

Comment: @JohnKattenhorn: Could you please provide the code you've used to copy the xml files? I'm fighting with the same issue.

Comment: @chris6523 I got the copy of xml files to work by changing the WebHost's .csproj, instead of the .sfproj. Instructions here (vdevappa's comment) https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/795#issuecomment-306202030

Comment: Is there any description of where files end up in the sf system?  Trying to figure out where to put my included files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for the coping whole **Guest Executable** folder, thanks Matt and AdamC

```
<Target Name="AfterPackage" AfterTargets="Package">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ExamapleServiceDir Include="$(SolutionDir)\ExamapleService\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy 
    SourceFiles="@(ExamapleServiceDir)" 
    DestinationFiles="@(ExamapleServiceDir->'$(PackageLocation)\ExamapleServicePkg\Code\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" 
    SkipUnchangedFiles="true" 
    OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" 
    Retries="3" 
    RetryDelayMilliseconds="300" />
</Target>
```

```
DestinationFiles="@(ExamapleServiceDir->'$(ProjectDir)\ApplicationPackageRoot\ExamapleServicePkg\Code\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
```

if you don't like SF complaints about Service pkg changed every publish

It has a huge advantage over **Content Linking** because it doesn't slow down VS performance (5 sec for context window open in my project, OMG)

```
<Content Include="..\ExamapleService\**\*.*">
  <Link>ApplicationPackageRoot\ExamapleServicePkg\Code\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
</Content>
```