# Deploying additional DLLs with service with ServiceFabric via Visual Studio

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I have a service that requires additional C++ DLLs to be deployed that are invoked via pinvoke. My service currently assumes that C++ DLLs are going to sit right beside the currently executing assembly. I'm having a really tough time understanding how I get those add those so that they are part of the code package. I've tried creating a post-build event handler against my service that copies the DLLs to the bin, but the package step doesn't seem to pick it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my response here: [Service Fabric include additional files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278074/service-fabric-include-additional-files).  You can accomplish this in one of two ways: specify the files as Content files of your service project, or manually copy the files to the service package in a post-Package MSBuild step from the application project.